# A Windows C compiler that doesn't split arguments in its runtime libraries?

Tags: c, windows, command-line

I have heard that in Windows, parameters are passed a single parameter, and then the program splits it into arguments, either in its runtime libraries, or sometimes, in the actual code.

I've heard that most C/C++ compilers do it in runtime libararies (for example, TCC - [Tiny C Compiler](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_C_Compiler), which I downloaded)

Are there any C compilers I can download, that don't? Any links to them?

And in such a compiler, would `argsv[0]` have the whole string?

**Added**

It's based on what this person ([jdedb](https://superuser.com/users/38062/jdebp)) said in Super User question *[Can't pipe or redirect Cygwin grep output](https://superuser.com/questions/358550/cant-pipe-or-redirect-cygwin-grep-output/358588#358588)*, after seeming to suggest that I ask on Stack Overflow.

"It's up to the called program to split the command tail into words, if it wants to operate in Unix (and C language) fashion. (The runtime support libraries of most C and C++ language implementations for Win32 do this splitting behind the scenes."

He said it's the compilers.. But [according to Necrolis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8267051/a-windows-c-compiler-that-doesnt-split-arguments-in-its-runtime-libraries/8267093#8267093), it's not the compiler.
(added- Necrolis commented correcting my misreading, compiler!=runtime library)

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve with this?

Comment: Why would you need this?

Comment: Note that (a) I actually said runtime libraries; and (b) I did specifically mention _other programming languages_ doing things in yet other ways.

Comment: @JdeBP ok but regarding C/C++ specifically, you said, as quoted in my question "of most C and C++ language implementations"  Doesn't that suggest that you meant some don't? I am asking, can you point to any, and are they available for download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are on Windows, just use [`GetCommandLine`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683156%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). This is how most CRT wrappers get the command line to split to start with.

As for your actual question, it's not the compiler, but the CRT startup wrapper that they use. If you implement `mainCRTstartup`, and override the entrypoint with it, you can do whatever you want. A good example of how it works can be seen [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/library/tlibc.aspx).

Comment: see question, i've updated it to include the place I heard that it was the compiler.

Comment: @barlop: you are miss-reading that quote, "runtime support libraries" != compiler. In tcc, the CRT wrapper is in `crt1.c`, its compiled by the compiler, but its not part of it.

Comment: ok, so to rephrase then.. could you point me to a download link of any C/C++ implementations whose runtime support libraries don't split the command line into arguments?

Comment: @barlop: none exist that I know of (mainly cause this is a standard, see pmg's answer), but you can easily alter them to do so (like tcc's) or roll your own, see my second link.

Comment: looks like visual c++ express does it in stdargv.c  http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=FpDTjfud   which doesn't use GetCommandLine, it uses _acmdlm , mentioned in comments there and documented here http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff770586.aspx   That variable stores it.

Comment: @barlop: have a look at crt0.c in the same folder, you'll notice `_tcmdln = (_TSCHAR *)GetCommandLineT();` ;)

Answer (score 0):

That "parameter splitting" is the way mandated by [the C99 Standard (PDF file)](http://www.open-std.org/JTC1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1256.pdf) in 5.1.2.2.1.

If an implementation (compiler + library + options) recognizes but does not separate the program name from the other parameters (and parameters from each other) it is not conforming.

*Of course, if you use a free-standing implementation none of this applies.*

Comment: Incorrect.  Whether the program name is split from the command tail is immaterial, given that I was talking about _splitting the command tail_.  The standard — quite rightly, since it has no concept of command tails — _does not_ mandate anything with reference to splitting the command tail, _except_ that individual implementations document what they actually do to populate `argv`.  There's _no_ mandate to split a command tail into more than one parameter.  The standard merely defines "program parameters" as its name for what the program receives here.  That's why those words are italicized.

Comment: I meant `argv[0]`, in a conforming implementation, cannot point to `"a.out --help --extended"` as the OP seemed to be asking. Of course you can have `argv[0]` point to `"a.out"` and `argv[1]` point to `"--help --extended"`.